# save-excursion doesn't restore the currently visible buffer?

Tags: window, save-excursion

From the `save-excursion` docstring:

> Save point, mark, and current buffer; execute BODY; restore those things.

My understanding was that the restored buffer would again be visible following the evaluation of the body, but that appears not to be the case.  A basic function demonstrating the behavior that I find surprising:

```
(defun test-excursion ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (find-file "just-a-test"))
  (insert "blah"))
```

On my system (using `emacs -q`; running Debian version 24.5.1) interactively running this function using `M-x test-excursion` I get most of the behavior I expect.  A new empty file buffer is created (there is no such file on disk) named "just-a-test" and "blah" is inserted in the scratch buffer that I happened to have open at the time.  **However; the buffer that remains visible is "just-a-test" and not "*scratch*" which was `(current-buffer)` at the time the command was invoked.**  No additional windows were created.  It is only apparent by switching back to "*scratch*" that the string was inserted as expected.

My memory may be inaccurate on this, but I recall using `save-excursion` when writing a function and observing the alternate behavior (the restored buffer restored as visible).  Is there any chance that this behavior has changed or that there has been a regression in 24.5.1?  I know that the definition has changed in 25.  I checked on another system (also 24.5.1) and observed the same behavior as my system.  Evaluation non-interactively (via `eval-last-sexp`) yields the same.  `switch-buffer` and `save-current-buffer` also yield the same.

My understanding is that each window (in the emacs sense) has a current buffer (**edit**: perhaps appropriately referred to simply as the "displayed buffer" and is returned by `current-buffer` when the window has focus) which necessarily is visible and there are no other conceptions of a "visible buffer".  If `save-excursion` restores the current buffer then shouldn't it be visible?

I've been scratching my head at this one for a while.  I hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The current buffer need not be visible in a window.

You're looking for `save-window-excursion` (or quite possibly a combination of the two).

n.b. <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> `^save-` will point out all of the following:

```
save-current-buffer
  Function: Record which buffer is current; execute BODY; make that
            buffer current.

save-excursion
  Function: Save point, mark, and current buffer; execute BODY;
            restore those things.

save-match-data
  Macro: Execute the BODY forms, restoring the global value of the
         match data.

save-restriction
  Function: Execute BODY, saving and restoring current buffer's
            restrictions.

save-selected-window
  Macro: Execute BODY, then select the previously selected window.

save-window-excursion
  Macro: Execute BODY, then restore previous window configuration.
```

Comment: Do all windows necessarily lack focus when current-buffer is not visible?  I don't ever recall observing emacs in such a state, but it would be a rare condition in the first place.

Comment: The documentation for `set-buffer` suggests that the command loop restores the current buffer to the selected window's buffer at the end of each command, in which case that wouldn't be a state that Emacs could get into.

Comment: Confirmed by `(elisp) Current Buffer` which states "When an editing command returns to the editor command loop, Emacs automatically calls ‘set-buffer’ on the buffer shown in the selected window."

Answer (score 4):

Facing a similar problem, I realize this behavior is due to `find-file` in particular. I didn't try using `save-window-excursion` instead of `save-excursion`. What I used instead was

```
(with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect "just-a-test")
 (insert "blah"))
```

That way, `just-a-test` is loaded or switched to if it already visited in the background. It remains open. As far as I can see, for this simple example the two methods (this and the one by phils) is a matter of taste.